# How to undo meteor add accounts-google

Tags: meteor

Added accounts-google to my app, just looking to remove it, total beginner here. I used the command meteor add accounts-google, but meteor undo and meteor destroy aren't valid commands.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, meteor remove accounts-google

thanks anyway.